# How can I mirror this animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, less

I have a panel on the left side of my screen that flips out when activated. As you move your mouse around, it slightly alters the `rotateY` transform for a nice interactive effect.  I want to mirror this on the right side of the screen, but every adjustment I make just causes the panel to freak out when you move the mouse.

What adjustments need to be made to the second jquery function to mirror the effect?  I tried a lot of things including the current code which is replacing `x = x + 15` with `x = 360 - (x + 15)`.  It's close, but still not right.

```js
$(document).on('mousemove','#viewport1 .menu',function( event ) {
  var x = Math.round(event.pageX / $(this).width() * 10);
  x = x + 15;
  $(this).css('transform','rotateY(' + x + 'deg)');
});


$(document).on('mousemove','#viewport2 .menu',function( event ) {
  var x = Math.round(event.pageX / $(this).width() * 10);
  x = 360 - (x + 15);  //this is almost but not quite right...
  $(this).css('transform','rotateY(' + x + 'deg)');
});
```

```css
.viewport {
    perspective: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom:0; width: 30%;
    padding: 5px;
}
.menu {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
#viewport1 {
    left: 0;
}
#viewport1 .menu {
    perspective-origin: left;
    transform-origin: left;
    transform: rotateY(15deg);
}

#viewport2 {
    text-align: right;
    right: 0;
}
#viewport2 .menu {
  perspective-origin: right;
  transform-origin: right;
  transform: rotateY(345deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="viewport1" class="viewport">
  <div class="menu">HOVER ME!</div>
</div>
<div id="viewport2" class="viewport">
  <div class="menu">HOVER ME!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I spent 20 minutes removing everything project dependent so that it is reproducible here even though I believe it is likely a simple math problem that someone knowledgeable will be able to solve quickly without seeing an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `event.pageX`, which is the position of the mouse pointer, relative to the left edge of the document, to calculate the rotation of the `<div>`. You need to substract the left offset: `$(this).offset().left`. After that you change `x+15` to `x-15` and you get the mirrored effect.

```js
$(document).on('mousemove','#viewport1 .menu',function( event ) {
 var x = Math.round(event.pageX / $(this).width() * 10);
  
 x = x + 15;
 $(this).css('transform','rotateY(' + x + 'deg)');
});


$(document).on('mousemove','#viewport2 .menu',function( event ) {
 var x = Math.round((event.pageX - $(this).offset().left) / $(this).width() * 10);
  
 x = x - 15;
 $(this).css('transform','rotateY(' + x + 'deg)');
});
```

```css
.viewport {
  perspective: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom:0; width: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}
#viewport1 {
  left: 0;
}
#viewport1 .menu {
  perspective-origin: left;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: rotateY(15deg);
}

#viewport2 {
text-align: right;
  right: 0;
}
#viewport2 .menu {
  perspective-origin: right;
  transform-origin: right;
  transform: rotateY(345deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="viewport1" class="viewport">
  <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
<div id="viewport2" class="viewport">
  <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
```